# Why is packagist not seeing/using my latest releases when I install my package?

Tags: packagist

I can see my latest releases in Packagist but when I install the package it uses an older one and trying to install using the version number gives "Could not find package..." error.

**Example:**

I create a new release and push to GitHub.

I scan in Packagist and it finds the new release.

I install the package and it installs an older release and can't find the new one.

Link to Package: https://packagist.org/packages/3cwebdev/drupal-composer-install

Link to GitHub repo: https://github.com/3CWebDev/drupal-composer-install

v1.13.0 is the latest release but it always installs 1.10